# how to post message user's recent activity in facebook using php

Tags: php, facebook

I am new to facebook app development. I am using this code:

```
$attachment = array('message' => "Testing message ",
                    link' => 'http://www.google.com/');
if(!($sendMessage = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment))){
                                 $errors= error_get_last();
                                 echo "Facebook publish error: ".$errors['type'];
                                 echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
                                      }'
```

This code posting the message in user's timeline but I want to post message in his recent activity.

Answer (score 0):

The post will automatically appear in recent activity. This section aggregates activity made in various places, and is generated by Facebook. It cannot be written to directly.

Comment: Thanks for replying... but in my case the post is not appearing in recent activity...